# How to call class function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

New to JavaScript so might be something simple.

**Getting an Error:**

> ball.html:46 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Why this is happening? I am new to JavaScript. But I tried everything in my knowledge to fix it. Tried removing the `function` but then it gives error:

> draw() function is not defined in repeatMe() function.

**HTML and JavaScript:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
          background-color: white;
      }

      canvas { 
        border: 3px solid black; 
    }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <canvas id="canvas-for-ball" height="800px" width="800px"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Gets a handle to the element with id canvasOne.
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-for-ball");
      // Get a 2D context for the canvas.
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      // The vertical location of the ball.
      var y = 10;
      var x = 10;
      var ballRadius = 3;
      var ySpeed = 1;

      class Ball {
        constructor(x, y, ballRadius, ySpeed) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y
            this.ballRadius = BallRadius;
            this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
        }//endConstructor

        function drawball() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        }//endDrawball

        function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(1, 1, 800, 800);
            drawball(); 
        }//endDraw

        function move() {
            // Update the y location.
            y += ySpeed;
            console.log(y);
        }
      } //endBall


      // A function to repeat every time the animation loops.
      function repeatme() {
        // Draw the ball (stroked, not filled).
        draw();
        move();

        //catch ball at bottom
        if (y == 800)
        {
             ySpeed = 0;
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(repeatme);
      }

      // Get the animation going.
      repeatme();
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Functions defined in a class don't need the function prefix. `function drawball()` should just be `drawball()` You are confusing a few concepts here so I will throw together a quick example for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to see this before jumping into using JavaScript.[Classes in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and few basics of programing in OOPS.

The issue you are facing is calling a function which doesn't exist. Also you have created class wrongly, this is not how functions are created in class in JavaScript.
Also you can't access class function directly, that's why they are in class. Need to create object of that class and that object will be used to call class function.

Change to this:

```
class Ball {
    constructor(x, y, ballRadius, ySpeed) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y
        this.ballRadius = BallRadius;
        this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
    }//endConstructor

    drawball() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    }//endDrawball

    draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(1, 1, 800, 800);
        drawball(); 
    }//endDraw

    move() {
        // Update the y location.
        y += ySpeed;
        console.log(y);
    }
  } //endBall

  let Ball = new Ball(x, y, ballRadius, ySpeed);
  // Note this is constructor calling so pass value for these arguments here

// A function to repeat every time the animation loops.
function repeatme() {

    // Draw the ball (stroked, not filled).
    Ball.draw();
    Ball.move();

    //catch ball at bottom
    if (Ball.y == 800)
    {
         Ball.ySpeed = 0;
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(repeatme);
}
```

Would highly recommend to read few docs before jumping into JavaScript, as it's get confusing with [callsbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) and many more.

Comment: should `let Ball = new Ball(x, y, ballRadius, ySpeed);` really be inside the loop? I think this will cause unintended effects, namely multiple balls all being drawn at the same spot and not moving after the initial call. Should probably move that declaration out of the loop.

Comment: Also you never define x, y, ballRadius or ySpeed so your call to the constructor will fail.

Comment: I just added code that needed to be changed, it's called common sense. All these variables are already declared, and doesn't need to change that part.

Comment: Look, I'm not looking to start a fight. I noticed some issues in your code and pointed it out. It's not a personal attack, its constructive feedback.

Comment: Yeah and I accepted point made by you on moving out object creating of class inside a recursive function. It's a nice and good thing to do. But to write down whole code again which had nothing to do with solution, doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Deleted - I'm not arguing with you about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem here in that you're attempting to invoke some functions which don't exist:

```
  function repeatme() {
    // Draw the ball (stroked, not filled).
    draw(); //<-- Where is this function?
    move(); //<-- Where is this function?

    //catch ball at bottom
    if (y == 800)
    {
         ySpeed = 0;
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(repeatme);
  }
```

I presume you want to use the functions which are part of the ball class.  If so, you need to spin off a new instance of a Ball, and access the functions from there...:

```
  function repeatme() {
    // Draw the ball (stroked, not filled).
    let ball = new Ball(x, y, ballRadius, ySpeed); //<--- create a new ball instance
    ball.draw(); //<-- invoke the function which resides on a ball
    ball.move(); //<-- invoke the function which resides on a ball

    //catch ball at bottom
    if (y == 800)
    {
         ySpeed = 0;
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(repeatme);
  }
```

That "might" fix your code, but there is also a lot of other concepts happening here that you need to research.  For example, you have some variables scoped OUTSIDE the context of a Ball, yet inside your Ball class, you are referencing them.  Thus, you've essentially created a closure here... probably by accident.

You ought to just let the Ball do it's thing, without all these scoped variables... sort've like so:

```
// Gets a handle to the element with id canvasOne.
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-for-ball");
      // Get a 2D context for the canvas.
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//< -- Notice I removes these vars here, since we really just want to feed those into the constructor of a Ball...

      class Ball {
        constructor(x, y, ballRadius, ySpeed) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y
            this.ballRadius = ballRadius;
            this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
        }//endConstructor

        drawball() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.ballRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        }//endDrawball

        draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(1, 1, 800, 800);
            this.drawball(); 
        }//endDraw

        move() {
            // Update the y location.
            this.y += this.ySpeed;
            console.log(this.y);
        }
      } //endBall


      // A function to repeat every time the animation loops.
      function repeatme() {
        // Draw the ball (stroked, not filled).
         // The vertical location of the ball.  Remember the variables above?  Now the values are fed into here instead...
        let ball = new Ball(10, 10, 3, 1)
        ball.draw();
        ball.move();

        //catch ball at bottom
        if (ball.y == 800)
        {
             ball.ySpeed = 0;
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(repeatme);
      }

      // Get the animation going.
      repeatme();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just defined below functions out of `class()`

```
function drawball() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    }//endDrawball

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(1, 1, 800, 800);
        drawball(); 
    }//endDraw

    function move() {
        // Update the y location.
        y += ySpeed;
        console.log(y);
    }
```

**Updated working code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
          background-color: white;
      }

      canvas { 
        border: 3px solid black; 
    }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <canvas id="canvas-for-ball" height="800px" width="800px"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Gets a handle to the element with id canvasOne.
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-for-ball");
      // Get a 2D context for the canvas.
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      // The vertical location of the ball.
      var y = 10;
      var x = 10;
      var ballRadius = 3;
      var ySpeed = 1;

      class Ball {
        constructor(x, y, ballRadius, ySpeed) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y
            this.ballRadius = BallRadius;
            this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
        }//endConstructor

      } //endBall

        function drawball() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        }//endDrawball

        function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(1, 1, 800, 800);
            drawball(); 
        }//endDraw

        function move() {
            // Update the y location.
            y += ySpeed;
            console.log(y);
        }
      // A function to repeat every time the animation loops.
      function repeatme() {
        // Draw the ball (stroked, not filled).
        draw();
        move();

        //catch ball at bottom
        if (y == 800)
        {
             ySpeed = 0;
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(repeatme);
      }

      // Get the animation going.
      repeatme();
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The root of the issue is that you are creating a class but then never creating an instance of that class to call your functions on. Here is a cleaned up functioning example with comments explaining what things are doing differently.

```js
// Gets a handle to the element with id canvasOne.
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-for-ball");
// Get a 2D context for the canvas.
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// The vertical location of the ball.
var y = 10;
var x = 10;
var ballRadius = 3;
var ySpeed = 1;

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y, ballRadius, ySpeed) {
    // changed these to set the private members
    this._x = x;
    this._y = y
    // updated the assignment here, it had the wrong case
    this._ballRadius = ballRadius;
    this._ySpeed = ySpeed;
  } //endConstructor
  
  // added a setter for ySpeed so you can acess it outside of the class
  set VerticleSpeed(val){
    this._ySpeed = val;
  }
  
  // added a getter/setter for y so you can access it outside of the class
  get VerticlePosition(){
    return this._y;
  }
  
  // remove the function keyword, it's not needed
  drawball() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    // updated this to reference the properties on the class
    ctx.arc(this._x, this._y, this._ballRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
  } //endDrawball

  // remove the function keyword, it's not needed
  draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(1, 1, 800, 800);
    this.drawball();
  } //endDraw

  // remove the function keyword, it's not needed
  move() {
    // Update the y location.
    // updated this to reference the properties on the class
    this._y += this._ySpeed;
    console.log("Ball position", this._y);
  }
} //endBall


// A function to repeat every time the animation loops.
function repeatme() {
  // Draw the ball (stroked, not filled).
  // upated to call the functions on the instance of the class
  myBall.draw();
  myBall.move();

  //catch ball at bottom
  // changed to check the property on the instance of the class
  // changed this bit to make it bounce and if its outside the bounds, this is just me showing off and having fun with this example
  
  if (myBall.VerticlePosition >= canvas.height) {
    // changed to assign the property on the instance of the class
    myBall.VerticleSpeed = -ySpeed;
  } else if (myBall.VerticlePosition <= 0){
    myBall.VerticleSpeed = ySpeed;
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(repeatme);
}

// create an instance of your class
let myBall = new Ball(x, y, ballRadius, ySpeed)
// Get the animation going.
repeatme();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

canvas {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 25px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Canvas</title>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="canvas-for-ball" height="150px" width="400px"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```